# NGINX how to redirect all traffic from a port to a folder

Tags: nginx-config

I have experience with other web servers, but I am migrating to Nginx and I run into this problem.

On a computer I have several domains hosted (domain1.com.ar, domain2.net, domain3.xyz). I need all traffic to a certain port to go to a certain folder, that is, everything that goes to domain1.com.ar:1234 or domain2.net:1234 or domain3.xyz:1234 is redirected to the / www / folder foldercommun.
the query is:

How do I do it? Is it necessary to modify the configuration of each website one by one or can I do it at the server level?

Thanks in advance for helping me in this new world.

Answer (score 1):

Would this be enough?

```
server {
    listen 1234;
    server_name *.domain1.com.ar *.domain2.net *.domain3.xyz;
    location / {
        root  /www/folder/foldercommun;
    }
}
```

If not, please tell in the comments section.